Why ExpandRow is not working after adding a new row?
In my application, I am using 2 data grids in one another like master-detail. In detail, I am using inline editing like in Radzen Blazor DataGrid InLine Editing
If I click to Add Order Detail and enter data then save  (OnCreateRowDetail) it. I manage to stay on the same page but I want to keep the row expanded but it is collapsed.
Here is the simplified code:
@using System.Globalization
@using System.Security.Claims
@using AutoMapper
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

@inject AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider
@inject IMapper Mapper
@inject ILogger<OrderList> _logger
@implements IDisposable

<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="false" RowClick="RowClick" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
                Data="@_ordersDto" TItem="OrderDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
                ShowExpandColumn="false" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnResize="true" >
<Template Context="order">
<RadzenTabs>
<Tabs>
<RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
<div id="wrapper">
    <RadzenButton class="rz-background-color-success-light" Icon="add_circle_outline" style="margin-bottom: 10px" Text="Add Order Detail" Click="@(() => InsertDetailRow(order.Id))" Disabled="@(_detailToInsert != null)" Size="ButtonSize.Small"/>

</div>
<RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="@(_detailToInsert == null)" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowSorting="@(_detailToInsert == null)" Data="@order.OrderDetailsDto"
                TItem="OrderDetailDto" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true"
                                    AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px" Density="Density.Compact" >
<Columns>

<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="ProductCode" Title="Product  Code" OrderIndex="2">
    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.ProductCode" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="ProductCode" />        
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="Quantity" Title="Quantity" OrderIndex="7">
    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
        <RadzenNumeric TValue="int" Min="1" @bind-Value="orderDetail.Quantity" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="Quantity"/>        
    </EditTemplate>    
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="CostRatio" Title="Cost Ratio" OrderIndex="10">
    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
        <RadzenNumeric TValue="double" Min="0" @bind-Value="orderDetail.CostRatio" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="CostRatio"/>
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Property="PoNotes" Title="PO Notes" OrderIndex="23">
    <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
        <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.PoNotes" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="PoNotes"/>
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetailDto" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200px" OrderIndex="24">
    <Template Context="detail">
        <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>
    </Template>
    <EditTemplate Context="detail">
        <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
        </RadzenButton>        
    </EditTemplate>
</RadzenDataGridColumn>
</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
</RadzenTabsItem>

</Tabs>
</RadzenTabs>
</Template>
<Columns>
    
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Property="Status" Title="Status" Width="100px">

    </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDto" Context="order" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120px">
        <Template Context="order">
            <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRow(order))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>               
        </Template>        
    </RadzenDataGridColumn>

</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>

@code {
   

    IList<OrderDto?> SelectedOrders { get; set; }
    IQueryable<OrderDto?> _ordersDto;
    IQueryable<Order?> _order;   

    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDto?> _grid;
    RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetailDto> _gridDetail;

    OrderDto? _orderToInsert;
    OrderDetailDto? _detailToInsert;
    OrderDto orders;
    Order orderMap;
    OrderDetail orderDetailMap;
    
    int? current_page;
    int? pageIndex;
    
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _grid.SettingsChanged = new EventCallback<DataGridSettings>(this, async (DataGridSettings settings) =>
            {
                current_page = settings.CurrentPage;
            });
        }
        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
   
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
        _order = ViewOrdersUseCase.Execute(user);
        _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order);
           
        SelectedOrders = new List<OrderDto?> { _ordersDto.FirstOrDefault() };
        
    }
    
    private async Task RowClick(DataGridRowMouseEventArgs<OrderDto> mouseClick)
    {
        await _grid!.ExpandRow(mouseClick.Data);
        SelectedOrders = _ordersDto.Where(o => o.Id == mouseClick.Data.Id).ToList();

        if (SelectedOrders.Count > 0)
        {
            if (SelectedOrders[0].Status == "Completed" || SelectedOrders[0].Status == "Cancelled")
            {
                _detailToInsert = new OrderDetailDto();
            }
            else
            {
                _detailToInsert = null;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Add a method to find the parent OrderDto of a given OrderDetailDto
    private OrderDto? GetParentOrder(OrderDetailDto detail)
    {
        return _ordersDto.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrderDetailsDto.Any(d => d.Id == detail.Id));
    }

    private async Task OnCreateRowDetail(OrderDetailDto? orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            orderDetailMap = new OrderDetail();
            Mapper.Map(orderDetail, orderDetailMap);

            // Add the new order detail to the database
            var addedOrderDetail = await AddOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetailMap);

            Mapper.Map(addedOrderDetail, orderDetail);
            // Find the parent order
            var parentOrder = GetParentOrder(orderDetail);

            if (parentOrder != null)
            {
                pageIndex = current_page;
                _order = ViewOrdersUseCase.Execute(user);
                _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order);

                await _gridDetail.GoToPage((int)pageIndex);
                await _grid.ExpandRow(_ordersDto.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == parentOrder.Id));

                
            }
            
        }
    }    

    private async Task OnUpdateRowDetail(OrderDetailDto orderDetail)
    {
        if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
        {
            _detailToInsert = null;
        }

        if (orderDetail != null)
        {
            orderDetailMap = new OrderDetail();
            Mapper.Map(orderDetail, orderDetailMap);

            // Update the order detail in the database
            var updatedOrderDetail = await EditOrderDetailUseCase.ExecuteAsync(orderDetailMap);

            // Find the parent order
            var parentOrder = GetParentOrder(orderDetail);

            if (parentOrder != null)
            {
                parentOrder.OrderDetailsDto = Mapper.Map<List<OrderDetailDto>>(
                    await ViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase.ExecuteAsync(parentOrder.Id)
                );

                // Notify Blazor of the changes 
                StateHasChanged(); 
            }
        } 
    }

    async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetailDto orderDetail)
    {
        await _gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
    }     

    async Task SaveRowDetail(OrderDetailDto orderDetail)
    {
        await _gridDetail.UpdateRow(orderDetail);

        if (orderDetail.ProductCode != null)
        {
            if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
            {
                _detailToInsert = null;
            }
        }

        await _gridDetail.ExpandRow(orderDetail);
        StateHasChanged();

    }
   
}


public interface IViewOrdersUseCase
{
    IQueryable<CoreBusiness.Order?> Execute(ClaimsPrincipal user);
}
public class ViewOrdersUseCase : IViewOrdersUseCase
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

    public ViewOrdersUseCase(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public IQueryable<Order?> Execute(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        return _orderRepository.GetOrders(user);
    }
}
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    IQueryable<Order?> GetOrders(ClaimsPrincipal user);
}
    public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> _db;

        public OrderRepository(IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> db)
        { _db = db; }

        
        public IQueryable<Order?> GetOrders(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            var ctx = _db.CreateDbContext();
            IQueryable<Order> result = ctx.Orders
                .Include(d => d.OrderDetails.Where(od => od.IsActive == 1))
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.Id);

            if (!user.IsInRole("Administrators"))
            {
                result = result.Where(u => u.DoneBy == user.Identity.Name);
            }

            return result;
        }

        
    }


public interface IAddOrderDetailUseCase
{
    Task<CoreBusiness.OrderDetail> ExecuteAsync(CoreBusiness.OrderDetail orderDetail);
}
public class AddOrderDetailUseCase : IAddOrderDetailUseCase
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orderDetailRepository;

    public AddOrderDetailUseCase(IOrderDetailRepository orderDetailRepository)
    {
        this._orderDetailRepository = orderDetailRepository;
    }
    public async Task<OrderDetail> ExecuteAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        return await _orderDetailRepository.AddOrderDetailAsync(orderDetail);
    }
}
public interface IOrderDetailRepository
{
    Task<OrderDetail> AddOrderDetailAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail);
    
    Task<OrderDetail> UpdateOrderDetailAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail);

    
}
public class OrderDetailRepository : IOrderDetailRepository
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> _db;

    public OrderDetailRepository(IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<OrderDetail> AddOrderDetailAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        await using var ctx = await _db.CreateDbContextAsync();
        if (ctx.OrdersDetail.Any(x =>
                x.Id == orderDetail.Id)) return null;

        
        //Calculated Fields
        orderDetail.TotalBuyPrice = orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity;
        orderDetail.TotalSellPrice = orderDetail.Quantity * orderDetail.SellUnitPrice;
        orderDetail.UnitCost = orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice * (orderDetail.CostRatio / 100) + orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice;
        orderDetail.TotalUnitCost = orderDetail.Quantity * orderDetail.UnitCost;
        orderDetail.IsActive = 1; //Active
        orderDetail.PaymentStatus = "Pending Payment";
        orderDetail.Status = "Order Opened";
                
        ctx.OrdersDetail.Add(orderDetail);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        return orderDetail;
    }
    
    public async Task<OrderDetail> UpdateOrderDetailAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail)
{
    await using var ctx = await _db.CreateDbContextAsync();
    //detail
    var detail = await ctx.OrdersDetail
        .Include(v => v.Vendor)
        .Include(o => o.Order)
        .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == orderDetail.Id);
    
    //Order Statuses
    var statusCompleted = await ctx.OrdersDetail
        .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderDetail.OrderId && x.Id != orderDetail.Id)
        .AllAsync(c => c.Status == "Completed");
    var statusContinues = await ctx.OrdersDetail
        .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderDetail.OrderId && x.Id != orderDetail.Id)
        .AnyAsync(c => c.Status != "Completed");
    
    if (orderDetail != null && detail != null && vendor != null)
    {
        detail.Quantity = orderDetail.Quantity;
        detail.CostRatio = orderDetail.CostRatio;
        detail.Description = orderDetail.Description;
        detail.ProductCode = orderDetail.ProductCode;
        detail.ProductName = orderDetail.ProductName;
        detail.BuyUnitPrice = orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice;
        detail.ShippingNumber = orderDetail.ShippingNumber;
        detail.ShippingWeek = orderDetail.ShippingWeek;
        detail.Status = orderDetail.Status;
        detail.TotalBuyPrice = orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice * orderDetail.Quantity;
        detail.TotalSellPrice = orderDetail.Quantity * orderDetail.SellUnitPrice;
        detail.SellUnitPrice = orderDetail.SellUnitPrice;
        detail.UnitCost = orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice * (orderDetail.CostRatio / 100) + orderDetail.BuyUnitPrice;
        detail.TotalUnitCost = detail.UnitCost * orderDetail.Quantity;
        detail.Currency = orderDetail.Currency;
        detail.CustomerOrderNumber = orderDetail.CustomerOrderNumber;
        detail.CustomerStockCode = orderDetail.CustomerStockCode;
        detail.OrderId = orderDetail.OrderId;
        detail.TrackingNumber = orderDetail.TrackingNumber;
        detail.Warehouse = orderDetail.Warehouse;
        detail.PoNotes = orderDetail.PoNotes;
        detail.PaymentStatus = orderDetail.PaymentStatus;
        if (statusCompleted && orderDetail.Status == "Completed")
            detail.Order.Status = "Completed";
        if (statusContinues || orderDetail.Status != "Completed")
            detail.Order.Status = "Continues";
        detail.Vendor = vendor;

        if (detail.Status == "Completed")
        {
            detail.CompletionDateTime = orderDetail.CompletionDateTime ?? DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
        else
        {
            detail.CompletionDateTime = null;
        }
        
        ctx.OrdersDetail.Update(detail);
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return detail;
}
public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDetail>> GetOrderDetailsByOrderId(int orderId)
{
    await using var ctx = await _db.CreateDbContextAsync();
    return await ctx.OrdersDetail
        .Where(x => x.OrderId == orderId && x.IsActive == 1)
        .Include(x => x.Order).ToListAsync();
}
 }

public interface IEditOrderDetailUseCase
{
    Task<CoreBusiness.OrderDetail> ExecuteAsync(CoreBusiness.OrderDetail orderDetail);
}
public class EditOrderDetailUseCase : IEditOrderDetailUseCase
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orderDetailRepository;

    public EditOrderDetailUseCase(IOrderDetailRepository orderDetailRepository)
    {
        this._orderDetailRepository = orderDetailRepository;
    }

    public async Task<OrderDetail> ExecuteAsync(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        return await _orderDetailRepository.UpdateOrderDetailAsync(orderDetail);
    }
}


public interface IViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase
{
    Task<IEnumerable<CoreBusiness.OrderDetail>> ExecuteAsync(int orderId);
}
public class ViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase : IViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orderDetailRepository;
    public ViewOrderDetailsByOrderIdUseCase(IOrderDetailRepository orderDetailRepository)
    {
        _orderDetailRepository = orderDetailRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<OrderDetail>> ExecuteAsync(int orderId)
    {
        return await _orderDetailRepository.GetOrderDetailsByOrderId(orderId);
    }
}

public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string DoneBy { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetailDto> OrderDetailsDto { get; set; }
    

}
public class Order
{
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string DoneBy { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    


}
    public class OrderDetailDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string? ProductName { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public double BuyUnitPrice { get; set; }
        public double CostRatio { get; set; }
        public double UnitCost { get; set; }
        public double TotalBuyPrice { get; set; }
        public double? SellUnitPrice { get; set; }
        public double? TotalSellPrice { get; set; }
        public string? ShippingNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Status { get; set; }
        public string? TrackingNumber { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Currency { get; set; }
        public string? CustomerStockCode { get; set; }
        public string? CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }
        public int IsActive { get; set; }
        public double? TotalUnitCost { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public int VendorId { get; set; }
        public string? Warehouse { get; set; }
        public string? PaymentStatus { get; set; }
        public OrderDto OrderDto { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CompletionDateTime { get; set; }
        public int? ShippingWeek { get; set; }
        public string? PoNotes { get; set; }
    }
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string? ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double BuyUnitPrice { get; set; }

    public double CostRatio { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public double TotalBuyPrice { get; set; }
    public double? SellUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public double? TotalSellPrice { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string? ShippingNumber { get; set; }

    public string? Status { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string? TrackingNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(400)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    public string? Currency { get; set; }
    public string? CustomerStockCode { get; set; }
    public string? CustomerOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int IsActive { get; set; }
    public double? TotalUnitCost { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public string? Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string? PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? CompletionDateTime { get; set; }


    public int? ShippingWeek { get; set; }
    public string? PoNotes { get; set; }
}

Any idea why the row does NOT expand? _ordersDto.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == parentOrder.Id) returns the valid Order with newly added detail.

Can you add working minimal reproduction example?

Added related methods to the code

Thanks for providing additional information. Could you please refactor the code in such a way that the error still exists, but the code is functional? I am getting a lot of errors rn.

hope this time works

@GeorgeKarlinzer have you checked the code?

Yes, the code is still not running, please check what does minimal reproduction example mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example

@GeorgeKarlinzer, I created a project. You can get it from here https://github.com/raysefo/RadzenDataGridDemo

The problem is in line _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order); that changes data of the main grid and triggers grid reload and for some reason Radzen doesn't save expanded row in that case. What you want to do is  whether to update order directly after saving changes or handle expanded row yourself without using Radzen's mechanism.

If I don't add that line then datagrid won't updated. The question is how to update the order?

You should update order but not _ordersDto

You can check the behavior by removing the line _ordersDto = Mapper.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(_order); Order details will be added to order and row will be expanded

When I remove the line and try it, the parent order is collapsed and when I click another row and get back the one I newly added row, it is not displayed.

Did you also remove ExpandRow after _ordersDto = ...?

if I remove this line also await _grid.ExpandRow(_ordersDto.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == parentOrder.Id)); it is expanded but newly added row does not display on the detail grid

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
